# WPF, changing style of element inside ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm wondering if WPF offers a way to change the style of a named element defined inside a ControlTemplate, from a style declared somewhere else, as illustrated in the example below.

1. Lets redefine the ControlTemplate of a Label with a TextBlock named «MyTextBlock»

```
<Style x:Key="MyLabel" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

2. Lets inherit the style of the previously defined Label

```
<Style x:Key="MyNewLabel" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyLabel}">
    <Setter Property="{Binding {[SOME.EXPRESSION.TO.REACH.MyTextBlock???]}, Path=Foreground}" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if WPF offers a way to change the style of a named element defined inside a ControlTemplate, from a style declared somewhere else

Short answer: No.

You cannot access or set a property of the element (`TextBlock`) directly but you may set a property of the styled control (`Label`) that you bind to the element in the template, e.g.:

```
<Style x:Key="MyLabel" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MyNewLabel" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyLabel}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks mm8. In my real need, the style does not depend on an existing property like the Foreground property I used in my example... I know I can also add some extra dependency properties, but my question was really on the possibility to override the style of some named parts. So I'll probably accept your short answer.

Comment: Yes, I am afraid you cannot override the style of some named parts.